# Publish asp.net Website from CommandLine

Tags: asp.net, deployment, publish

I want to Publish asp.net Website .. Normally i do

- Open asp.net Project
- right click on Solution exploere and click on publish Website
- Asked for destination Path and I'm done...

But I don't want to follow all above steps all I want that .. I will click on .bat for publishing asp.net website

I followed all step's as mentioned here "How to publish Asp web sites with command prompt" => http://hajloo.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/how-to-publish-asp-web-sites-with-command-prompt/

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="PrecompileWeb">
    <AspNetCompiler
        VirtualPath="/Web"
        PhysicalPath="F:\Build_Automation\trunk\src\Portal\Web\"
        TargetPath="F:\Build_Automation\trunk\src\Portal\PrecompiledWeb\Web\"
        Force="true"
        Debug="true"
        FixedNames="True" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

But I m getting Error

```html
C:\>msbuild my.xml  /p:Configuration=Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.34209
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34209]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 9/24/2014 6:52:33 PM.
Project "C:\my.xml" on node 1 (default targets).
PrecompileWeb:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /Web -p
  "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\xxxx\xxxx\\"
  -f -d -fixednames C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PPatch\test\
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\xxxx\xxxx\web.co
nfig(8): error ASPCONFIG: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that a
ttribute names are case-sensitive. [C:\my.xml]
Done Building Project "C:\my.xml" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\my.xml" (default target) (1) ->
(PrecompileWeb target) ->
  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\xxxx\xxxx\web.
config(8): error ASPCONFIG: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that
 attribute names are case-sensitive. [C:\my.xml]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.17
```

I googled about that error i tried following solutions

- Registering the framework with IIS : aspnet_regiis -i => didn't helped
- Chose Build -> in Target Framework chose .NET Framework 4 => didn't helped

please suggest me .. is it possible ? if yes, where i m doing wrong or what i missing

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this from a regular command prompt or, as the article says you need to use, the Visual Studio command prompt under the VS tools directory?

Comment: StartMenu > All Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 > Visual Studio Tools > Visual Studio x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt (2010)

Comment: `targetFramework` was added in .net 4.5. According to the filepath, you are using VS2010 which uses .net 4.0. Try removing the attribute from the `web.config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Another Method and it worked fine for me

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedab/archive/2009/09/08/how-to-publish-a-website-using-command-prompt.aspx

Thanks